# Windows Forms Webbrower Control - handling modal documents

Tags: c#, vb.net, dom, webbrowser-control

I am using a WebBrowser control to interact with a third-party HTTPS site.  When certain links are clicked the site produces a new page that temporarily overlays the current page.

I get Navigate Complete, Download Complete, and Document Complete events.  However, although the URL parameters of these events are for the new page the browser's "Document" property is still set to the original (now hidden) page.

I need to interact with the DOM of the new page, but can't find any way to access it. Can anybody help?

As a matter of interest accessing the same page with Internet Explorer and entering debug mode allows me to see everything I need.

Answer (score 0):

have you hear about "awesomium" a client web browser for .net?
i think you should try with that.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  However, the project is fully developed, so I'd rather not have to refactor it around a new component at this stage.  The only reason this issue has arisen is because the third-party provider has made changes to their website.

Answer (score 0):

Further investigation revealed that the overlaying page was an iFrame.  The DOM I was looking for can be accessed as:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0].Document
```

In this case I know there is only one frame, but it would be equally possible to enumerate the Frames collection and locate the one with the expected details (e.g. URL).

Thanks to Muhamad for taking the time to respond.